# View the Query Execution in Entity Framework 5.0 Visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm newer to Entity Framework (5.0). I'm using Linq Method syntax to Querying the data from database. I Want to see the Difference between Eager Loading and Lazy loading at the time of Query Execution.How can i see that in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: You dont. You view it in the SQL profiler.

Comment: where it is in the VS 2013..?

Comment: It is not. It is in SSMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int? id)
{
if (id == null)
{
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}

// Commenting out original code to show how to use a raw SQL query.
//Department department = await db.Departments.FindAsync(id);

// Create and execute raw SQL query.
string query = "SELECT * FROM Department WHERE DepartmentID = @p0";
Department department = await db.Departments.SqlQuery(query, id).SingleOrDefaultAsync();

if (department == null)
{
    return HttpNotFound();
}
return View(department);
```

}

go to this link go thorugh this topic

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/advanced-entity-framework-scenarios-for-an-mvc-web-application